# Booting into the same Win10 within Virtual Box and directly thru dual booting

Tags: linux, virtualbox, multi-boot

On my pc I use dual boot Linux and Win10. Is it possible to boot that Win10 also from Linux thru Vritualbox occasionaly?

Regards

Comment: I think that can't be done. Even assuming it would recognize the partition instead of the virtual drive, it wouldn't boot with so different hardware, the virtualized hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Rather you can convert your windows disk into virtual hard disk and use it with virtual box(But you need to add the boot partitons using a windows iso).